# Send notifications to the user's devices

Tags: android, notifications, push, send

I want to build an application which sends notifications to the user's devices
what is the best technique to do this (I don't want GCM: Google Cloud Messaging)
I need some information about app on device and on server

Comment: please connect with us on stephen@pubnub.com and we can show you the coolest details about what you are asking for with non-GCM connectivity to devices at finger press speeds over great distances.

Answer (score 0):

One month ago, I was having the same issue, At that time (even now) I was not aware of any way or technology that may help me to perform communication from server to my android devices,  however from device to server was going on well, then I figured it out that when I want my device to get notified?The answer is when anything changes on the server.Then I decided to start some background services on my android device that keep a check on the servers, if the background services encounter any flags or changes on the servers, then this notification is sent to the user on account of the request and, the user is immediately notified by using Notification Manager.I guess there must be some more efficient technology or method to do it, but this was what worked out for me.You can refer to online tutorials on notification manager, services, asynctask to get what you want.Good luck